# ms access 2007 combining a multi-valued field with a single-value field in query

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

In Access 2007 I have a table with a column with a single-value field and a column with multi-valued field. Now I want to combine the values of these two columns in a new column in a query:

example:

```
the situation:
table 1              
column 1       column 2
1              2;3;6
2              1;4;7
4              3;1;2

what I wish to acomplish:
query
column n
1;2;3;6
2;1;4;7
4;3;1;2
```

thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT column1 & ";" & column2 FROM table1;
```

Comment: I tried as you wrote, but the column 2 in table 1 is a multi-valued field to which I enter different values via a combo box. When I enter the SQL a po

Comment: Try `SELECT column1 & ";" & column2.Value FROM table1;`

Comment: If I do it like this I get a query with more then three records:

Comment: If I do it like this I get a query with more then three records, but with only two values per field: first row "1;2" second row "1;3" third row "1;6" fourth row "2;1" fifth row "2;4" sixth row "2;7" seventh row "4;3" eight row "4;1" ninth row "4;2" (sorry if it is hard to read but I cant write it better)

Comment: What was the problem with the first approach (without .Value)? Your comment is not complete.

Comment: When I ttry the first approach a window pops up telling something like: A field with multiple value "column 2" is not valid in the expression "[table 1].[column 1]&";"&[column 2]".

Comment: It looks like you need some VBA to achieve it. Take a look at this thread: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-access/use-values-from-multivalue-lookup-field-to-build/f421f6c1-7872-4468-8431-155f721928ed?msgId=76152d73-8a27-4a5f-9e66-2ee32039cb86

Answer (score 0):

here is the sql that can    acomplish your results

```
 Select column1 & ";" & column2 from table1
```

Comment: Hiten004, you're missing an ampersand between the final quotation mark and column2.

Comment: When I try as you wrote a window pops up telling something like: A field with multiple value "column 2" is not valid in the expression "[table 1].[column 1]&";"&[column 2]".

Comment: I would remove all the space in the column name and table name. space will give you hard on the long run in access database. use the query builder to write the query. hope this help